# Why was my edit rejected even though it meets the poster's goals?

Tags: discussion, edits

I added the following edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9047656

The poster says "This works in Bootstrap 3" but it doesn't work in Bootstrap 3. I adjusted the code so that it works in Bootstrap 3 and added a link to the appropriate section of the Bootstrap 3 docs in the documentation of the edit.

My edit was rejected because it doesn't "preserve the goals of the post's owner".

Can someone help me understand why this edit is bad?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would reject an edit like this almost every time.

When you start changing the code in either a question or an answer, you have to be including code that the original author has added in a comment or it looks like you're changing the original intent of the author; or worse, vandalism.

In this situation, it is much better to reply to the original author in a comment pointing out the error. That way they can edit their own post as required should they so wish.

You shouldn't expect the users reviewing your edit to assume that you know what you're talking about. If the reviewers don't use bootstrap, there would be no way of them knowing if your edit was correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

**In short, your review is rejected for two reasons (in my eyes):**

1. It is just a matter of version. So, the answer was not wrong at that time and who would implement this would get it easily that what to do for the updated version.
2. As you are an under 2k reputation holder, it is a very silly thing to give you +2 reputation. You would get thousands of such types of thing which would not work in updated version. So, it is not logical to the community to give you such reputation only for updating according to new version.

---

See, its a 3-year-old question. It seems to me that at that time, either bootstrap 3 did not come or people was not used to with it. So, all the old answers used `shown`. In case of recent answers, your edited term is used. Some old answer also edited and approved like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8887315), but see, it is confusing to reviewers and it went upon the fortune!

Comment: Nitpick: the OP states that the answer claimed that it would work in bootstrap 3, but does not. So it was already wrong "at the time" - if the code was in fact wrong which would now be left up to the decision of edit approvers. But it is not a matter of versions as you claim.